# Perl extract filenames with regex

Tags: regex, xml, perl, matching

I am reading an xml file line by line and I all I care about is if the line

looks like this:

```
<DBGen Include="FileIWant.dbd" />
```

I need to make a new string that contains:

```
"FileIWant"
```

How do you replace magic with the correct regex?

```
 my $string = $row =~ /magic/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $string = $row =~ m/(.*)Include="(.*)\.(.*)".*/;

print $2, "\n";  #where $2 is the second parenthesis
```

Output:

```
FileIWant
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh..

```
$file_string = /Include="([^\."]*)\.[^\."]*"/
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse XML. It's dirty bad and wrong. Use an XML parser. `XML::Twig` is an example that I like. There are others, just stay away from `XML::Simple`, which is nasty.

```
my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );
my $filename = $twig -> findnodes('//DBGen',0)->att('Include');
```

This will locate the first node in your XML called `DBGEn` and extract the `Include` attribute.

It really is that simple, and it doesn't get tripped up by XML formatting - even that simple example you gave can be written several different - and perfectly valid - ways.

```
<xml
><DBGen
Include="FileIWant.dbd"
/></xml>
```

Or:

```
<xml><DBGen Include="FileIWant.dbd"/></xml>
```

Or:

```
<xml><DBGen Include="FileIWant.dbd"></DBGen></xml>
```

Or:

```
<xml>
   <DBGen 
       Include="FileIWant.dbd" 
   />
</xml>
```

Or could have other attributes which will mean it isn't then the first word after the element tag. It really is very icky to do this, and you don't need to - parsing it is very simple, and can still be done in one liners - the above, for example:

```
perl -0777 -MXML::Twig -e 'print XML::Twig->parse(<>)->findnodes('//DBGen',0)->att('Include');'
```

Comment: The legacy code unfortunately has to run on build systems that don't have a way to install extra libraries

Comment: That is unfortunate. All you have is a hammer, and the job here is putting in screws. I would suggest the best course of action is request the additional tools needed to do a proper job, but if you wish to increase your technical debt, then go for it.